# axis2 invokeNonBlocking NullPointerException

Tags: java, asynchronous, nullpointerexception, apache-axis, rpc

it is throw NullPointerException when i use RPCServiceClient and asynchronous call.But it is normal using RPCServiceClient.invokeBlocking.
my axis2 version is 1.6.4.

this is my code:

```js
public void sendMsg(String xmldata, AxisCallback callback) throws AxisFault {
     String webServiceURL = "http://171.8.212.68:8191/axis2/services/UserService";
        String sendflag = "true";
        if ("true".equals(sendflag)) {
           
            RPCServiceClient serviceClient = new RPCServiceClient();
            Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();
            EndpointReference targetEPR = new EndpointReference(webServiceURL);
            options.setTo(targetEPR);
            Object[] opAddEntryArgs = new Object[]{xmldata};
            QName opAddEntry = new QName("http://downstream.sysinterface.topsms.topnet.com", "sendMsg");
            if (callback == null) {
                callback = new AxisCallback() {
                    public void onComplete() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("***********onComplete");
                    }

                    public void onError(Exception exception) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("***********onError:"+exception.getMessage()+":"+ Arrays.toString(exception.getStackTrace()));
                        System.out.println(getStackTrace(exception));
                    }

                    public void onFault(MessageContext context) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("***********onFault");
                    }

                    public void onMessage(MessageContext context) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("***********onMessage");
                    }
                };
            }
            
            serviceClient.invokeNonBlocking(opAddEntry, opAddEntryArgs, callback);
            serviceClient.cleanupTransport();
            serviceClient.cleanup();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post both the working and non working code, as well as the stack trace of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is below:

```js
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext.needPropertyDifferences(AbstractContext.java:239)
 at org.apache.axis2.context.AbstractContext.setProperty(AbstractContext.java:202)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.getHttpClient(AbstractHTTPSender.java:568)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:157)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:396)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:223)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient$NonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(OutInAxisOperation.java:446)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:767)
```

Comment: my project is running on websphere 7.0.0.39